# Count entries for each directory in tree

Tags: shell-script, find, grep, directory

Say I have the following tree:

```
root:
d foo 
d bar

/foo:
d A
- tmp.txt

/bar:
d B
- tmp2.txt

/foo/A:
- tmp3.txt

/bar/B:
```

d = directory and
- = file

I need to answer the following question: which directory (excluding the root) contains the least entries?

I have tried

```
  find . | grep -oE '/([a-zA-Z]+/)+'
```

to get the number of occurrences for each directory. The problem is this command exclude empty directories, in this case /bar/B is excluded.

Any guidance on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU tools:

```
find . -printf '%h\0' -type d ! -name . -print0 |
  sort -z |
  uniq -zc |
  sort -zn |
  sed -z q |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

If you can guarantee that file names won't contain newline characters, you can simplify it to:

```
find . -printf '%h\n' -type d ! -name . -print | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | head -n1
```

(the number reported is the number of files in the directory minus 1 (`.` is counted, but not `..`)).

With `zsh`:

```
count() {
  set -- $REPLY/*(NDoN)
  REPLY=$#
}
print -r -- **/*(Do+count[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c \
    'printf -- "%-20s: " {};
    find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%i\n" | wc -l' \;
```

If you have this tree, (`tree` is a nice command btw.):

```
$ tree -a .
.
├── bar
│   ├── B
│   └── tmp2.txt
├── ff
├── .ff.swp
└── foo
    ├── A
    │   └── tmp3.txt
    ├── f2.txt
    ├── f3.txt
    └── tmp.txt
```

You get this:

```
.                   : 2
./foo               : 3
./foo/A             : 1
./bar               : 1
./bar/B             : 0
```

---

To list *one of the lesser* (more then one could have e.g. null files), one could do something like:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c \
    'find "{}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%i\n" | \
    wc -l | xargs printf "%-2d";
    printf ": %s\n" "{}" ' \; | sort -k1,1 | head -n 1
```

if folders does not contain newline.

---

If `-maxdepth` is not available, an alternative could be:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c \
    'printf -- "%-20s: " "{}";
    find "{}" ! -wholename "{}" -prune -type f -printf "%i\n" | wc -l' \;
```